# Wrapping an already existent class

Tags: python

I've run into a bug where an iterator which loops through data is giving the shorter then expected remainder at the end of the set before looping back to the beginning. I need all iterations to be exactly the same size so I'd like it to drop the leftover part. Unfortunately The iterator is called as an argument for another object so I have no control over when `__next__()` is called. The solution that comes to mind is to make a custom class that inherits from the iterator and only redefine `__next__()`.

I'm trying to do this as follows:

```py
class CleanIterator(NumpyArrayIterator):

    def __init__(self, _super):
        super=_super

    def __next__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.next(*args, **kwargs)

    def next(self, *args, **kwargs):
        while True:
            data= super.next(*args, **kwargs)

            # reject short data snippets
            if data[0].shape[0] == self.batch_size:
                return data

# .flow return a NumpyArrayIterator
data_generator= ImageDataGenerator().flow(
        valid_data, valid_labels,
        batch_size= 100)
data_generator= CleanIterator(data_generator)
```

This manages to inherit functions from multiple levels of inheritance, but only appears to inherit variables from NumpyArrayIterator.

As a result I get errors like this:

```
venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py", line 68, in __len__
    return (self.n + self.batch_size - 1) // self.batch_size  # round up
AttributeError: 'CleanIterator' object has no attribute 'n'
```

where NumpyArrayIterator inherits from Iterator. Iterator has variable `self.n` and function `__len__()`.

I've tried looking for the proper syntax but every example I can find builds the parent class from scratch rather than starting with an extant instance.

So I guess the question is: how do you create an new instance of child-class from an old instance of parent-class?

Comment: Your class is not a valid subclass of `NumpyArrayIterator`, because your `__init__()` method did not call the superclass's version of `__init__()` to allow it to perform needed initializations.  (Your method makes no sense, anyway - assigning a parameter to a local variable, that you do not use, accomplishes nothing.)

Comment: So how do I call `__init__()` for the super class and keep the data already in the super class insance I have.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you want. I am pretty confused as to what you are asking, does this answer your question?

```py
class first:
    def test_function(self):
        print('it works')

instance = first()

class secondary(instance.__class__):
    """This class adds functionality to the already existent instance of the First class"""
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def added_function(self):
        pass
```

As you see by using the `__class__` attribute of an instance we can access its class.

Comment: Sorry no. The class type I'm inheriting from for is `NumpyArrayIterator`, getting the instance to tell me that doesn't help much. I'm trying to make a new object that behaves exactly like the old one except for a small change to `__next__()`. That includes containing all the instance specific data that was already in the old class.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is filtering, cannot you just use `itertools.filterfalse`?

```
import itertools
...
data_generator = itertools.filterfalse(
                    (lambda x:x[0].shape[0] == x.batch_size),
                    data_generator)
```

Comment: great tool, I'll try to remember that for later. Unfortunately no though. The documentation says it's an iterator and there's iterator in the name, but it's not an iterator. Took a 2 hr dive into the source code to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def clean_itterator(fn, index_array, generator):
    while True:
        data= fn(index_array)

        # reject under-sized batches
        if data[0].shape[0] == generator.batch_size:
            return data
        return None

data_generator= ImageDataGenerator().flow(
        valid_data, valid_labels,
        batch_size= 100)

original_fn= data_generator._get_batches_of_transformed_samples

data_generator._get_batches_of_transformed_samples= \
    lambda index_array: clean_itterator(
        original_fn,
        index_array,
        data_generator)
```

It's ugly as sin and it doesn't work the way I'd like but it runs

Comment: I'm sorry that this is 1,000,000 miles from what I originally posted. The documentation said .flow() returns an iterator, and the class is named iterator. I thought they'd do something more elegant than 100% proprietary.